# Create a simple forward iterator which automatically wraps at the "end" of a circular buffer

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector, circular-buffer

I've created a simple circular buffer by inheriting std::vector and overloading its operator[] to modulo the desired index with the vector size:

```
template <typename T>
class circvector : public std::vector<T> {
public:
    T& operator[](size_t index) { return *(this->data() + index%this->size()); };       // modulo index by vector size when accessing with [] operator
};

int main()
{
    circvector<int> buffer;                         // create a circvector
    buffer.resize(10);                              // resize it
    std::iota(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), 0);     // fill with monotonically increasing integers

    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size() * 2; i++)
        std::cout << buffer[i] << " ";              // access elements with [] beyond the circvector size is safe
}
```

which correctly produces the output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I would also like to create a "smart" forward input iterator which supports operator++ (increment) and operator* (dereference) and **which automatically "wraps"** when advancing past the last element in the vector **back to the beginning** of the underlying vector to which it's associated.

This hypothetical iterator would allow, for example, easier execution of some functions in the algorithm library (which often take iterators as arguments) on a subset of the circvector without adding logic to check for and then split into two separate calls when the desired subset spans the end->start wrap of the circvector.

I've been reading up on creating custom iterators but descriptions get pretty hairy with information that seemingly satisfies requirements I don't *think* I need.  Add to that discussion of recent deprecation of std::iterator and I'm not sure where to even begin to create my own iterator, or associate it with my circvector class.

Can someone get me started with a minimally workable template to run with?

Comment: I guess an iterator over a circular buffer is against the very idea of a circular buffer. Does `std::stack` have a `begin` and an `end`? Also, if it wraps, how will some algorithms know where the end is?

Comment: Don’t waste time, use the one already made e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html

Comment: @ZDF I don't see why it would be against the idea.  What would be so wrong with iterating from element "begin()+8" to "begin()+12", and allow the iterator to automatically access the underlying vector elements at the start of the vector even if "+12" would otherwise increment past the last element in the vector?  Furthermore, why not allow iterating from "begin()" to "begin()+100" if one wanted to iterate over the buffer 10 times?  I agree an end() iterator wouldn't make much sense to have.

Comment: @4xy Thanks, I've run across the boost::circular_buffer before and figured I could just plug it in and try it, but I was also hoping to use this as an opportunity to learn more about custom smart iterators as well as have a solution which is only minimally modified from a std:vector for which I'm already familiar.

Comment: I do not see any practical use. A client needs `push_back` and `pop_front`.

Comment: @ZDF There is definitely a practical use... I allocate the entire buffer at the beginning with .resize() or .assign() and have no need to add or remove elements, only replace them or access them with [] operator or with my (hypothetical) iterator if I want to jump from Nth element to N+Mth element.  The push_back() and pop_front() methods would just call the underlying default std::vector methods and actually resize the buffer instead adding or subtracting from it in the circular fashion that the overloaded [] operator provides.

Comment: @4xy Looks like the boost::circular_buffer iterators do not exhibit the behavior I require. If you advance the boost::circular_buffer<>::iterator past the size of the circular_buffer, it crashes with a read access violation.

Answer (score 0):

This class appears to achieve the desired behavior, though it inherits from the deprecated std::iterator class:

```
template <typename T>
class circvector: public std::vector<T> {
public:
    T& operator[](size_t index_) { return *(this->data() + index_%this->size()); };     // modulo index_ by vector size when accessing with [] operator

    class iterator; // forward declaration

    iterator begin() { return circvector<T>::iterator(*this, 0); }
    iterator end() { return circvector<T>::iterator(*this, this->size()); } // will be same as begin() due to modulo in iterator constructor initializer list

private:

    class iterator : public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, T> {
    private:
        circvector<T>& container_;      // NOTE: ORDER MATTERS! // dependency injection
        size_t index_{ 0 };         // NOTE: ORDER MATTERS! // state of iterator

    public:
        T& operator*() const { return container_[index_]; }                                     // this uses the overloaded operator[] which includes modulo
        iterator& operator+(int N) { index_ = (index_ + N) % container_.size(); return *this; } // random increment by N
        iterator& operator++() { index_ = (index_ + 1) % container_.size(); return *this; }     // increment with modulo
        iterator operator++(int) { return ++(*this); }                                              // just calls prefix increment: operator++()
        bool operator!=(const iterator & right) const { return index_ != right.index_ % container_.size(); }
        bool operator==(const iterator & right) const { return index_ == right.index_ % container_.size(); }
        explicit iterator(circvector<T>& container, size_t index_ = 0) : container_(container), index_(index_ % container_.size()) {}       // constructor
    };
};
```

It was modified from https://lorenzotoso.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/defining-a-custom-iterator-in-c/

A test program is:

```
int main()
{
    circvector<int> buffer;
    buffer.assign({ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });

    auto start_offset{ 8 };
    auto end_offset{ start_offset + 5 };

    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++) std::cout << buffer[i] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::for_each(buffer.begin() + start_offset, buffer.begin() + end_offset, [](auto& i) { i = 42; });
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++) std::cout << buffer[i] << " ";
}
```

creating output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
42 42 42 3 4 5 6 7 42 42
```

The use of algorithms from begin() to end() of course no longer works, since begin()==end(). But you can operate on partial segments of the buffer using algorithms (like std::for_each as shown) as long as the length is 1 less than the full buffer size.